# useWindowDimensions returning wrong height

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm having problems with the useWindowDimensions hook in react-native returning a height that is way too small. The height it gives me is 36 pixels, while I know my actual screen height on the device I'm using to test is 568.

When I rotate my device to landscape orientation, the height corrects itself to the proper height.

I made a very simple expo project that logs the screen height when you press a button. Should be very quick to clone and get running if you have expo: https://github.com/PeterHSteele/window-dimensions-test . Some of the time (probably most of the time), the log is correct, but on repeated reloads it always shows the incorrect height eventually. Whether it's correct or not seems to be totally random as far as I can tell.

I have the same problem when I use react native community's useDimensions or the Dimensions API. Although, there is an older version of my project which doesn't seem to have the problem so maybe it's version compatibility issue:

Versions in that demo project that doesn't seem to work:

```
"expo": "~39.0.2"
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": ".63.3"
```

Versions in old version of my app that did work:

```
"expo": "~36.0.0",
"react": "~16.9.0",
"react-dom": "~16.9.0",
"react-native": ".63.3"
```

Comment: Same has been happening to us for a while, useDimensions().window.height === 36 seemingly randomly. Did you wind up finding a solution and/or creating an issue in the react-native github?

Comment: @raphaelrk No, after trying for a while I decided the problem must be specific to my device since it seemed to persist no matter what library (RN, RN Community, Dimensions API) I used. Interesting to see someone else is having the same problem though!

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29290

Comment: Im getting this problem but on an IOS tablet. I'm testing at the same time on an Android Phone without this issue. Randomly , before a device rotation I get a size of 36. After the rotation the values are correct.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you,
`import {Dimensions} from "react-native"`

Dimensions will return **height** and **width** of `window` or `screen` whatever you select.

it would be,

`const {height,width} = Dimensions.get("window")`

or

`const {height,width} = Dimensions.get("screen")`

Comment: OP mentioned: _"I have the same problem when I use react native community's useDimensions or the Dimensions API. "_

Comment: Thanks Akshar and Samuli, I did try using the Dimensions API one more time as a response to this suggestion but I'm still alternating between heights of 568 and 36